# How to load a node title of different language?

Tags: 8

In my case the noads are stored in three different languages. How can add a condition, where I specify the language for the title that need to be loaded?

```
foreach($references as $reference){
    if($node = Node::load($reference->nid)){
      $url = Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', array('node' => $node->id()))->toString();
      $link = '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$this->t($node->getTitle()).'</a>';
      $render .= '<li>'.$link.'</li>';
    }
```

Where $references is an array of nids.

Comment: In general, *never* use t() with user input (only as placeholders) as that could lead to security issues. Entities also have a toLink() method, wihch returns a Link object that has a toString(), so you can simplify your two lines to `$node->getTranslation()->toLink()->toString()`. There is also a `links` template, but it unfortunately doesn't work with Link objects, instead it expects a list of arrays with the keys title and url, which is an Url object that you can get with $node->toUrl().

Comment: And last, your $reference->nid object looks suspicously like a database query result. In case you are querying the node table, you should use an entity query instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can load the translation separately with [`ContentEntityBase::getTranslation`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3AgetTranslation/8.6.x), e.g.:

```
if ($node->hasTranslation('es')) {
  $translation = $node->getTranslation('es');
  $translated_title = $translation->label();
}
```